# How to implement Vertical Scrollbar in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console, scrollbar, filestream, hex-editors

I'm implementing an hex editor in the console. I have 2 "Windows" displayed, one for the hex numbers and one for the text. In between i want to visualize a scrollbar.

Here a photo for better understanding.

[image: 2 Windows with scrollbar]

Now my question:

I'm, not quite sure how to calculate the number of segments of the scrollbar and on which segment I'm currently. I'm using a file stream holding the bytes. I'm always displaying the number of bytes the left window can show. If the user presses arrow up or down, I'm reading the next or previous line of the stream.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that well?

---

EDIT:

My Scrollbar class is very minimalistic at the moment: It holds:

- int numberOfSegments
- int currentSegment
- Point position

The renderer knows then how to draw the scrollbar. Do you think that's enough for the Scrollbar class?

Comment: `I'm, not quite sure how to calculate the number of segments of the scrollbar` what exactly is stopping you? Every segment is 11 bytes, so the total number of segments is the file size divided by 11. Or do you mean the number of segments relative to the size of the console?

Comment: I mean: Let's assume the file stream holds bytes for 65.000 lines. In the picture I'm on the first "page" when pressing down, the next page appears. How do I calculate which segment is colored white with the black diamond when I'm lets say on page 265. And how would that scale when the window size changes

Comment: Say you can display 20 lines at a time on the screen (check `Console.WinowHeight`), it means you need 65.000 / 20 = 3250 pages to display everything. Your scrollbar has 20 segments as well, it means 3250 / 20 = 162 pages per segment. So 162 * 20 = 3240 lines per segment (plus or minus the rounding errors). Since in your layout the number of lines is the same as the size of the scrollbar, you can take a shortcut and directly compute 65.000 / 20 = 3250 lines per segment. So you need to move the diamond every 3250 lines

Comment: okay that's great! But how would you implement it that the renderer knows: aha, now I have to move the diamond? Naturally I would say: Render a page and than re render the scrollbar. But would you put something like a counter in the Scrollbar class and always when the counter reaches 0 the currentSegment Property changes?

Comment: If I were building a UI toolkit then I'd put a "height", "position", "currentValue" and "maximumValue" properties and have the scrollbar do the division. But since it's only for this one application, I'd directly feed the file offset to the scrollbar and have it compute the diamond position every time it renders.